# CakePHP join query with concat

Tags: cakephp, concatenation

Please I need assistance with running this query in CakePHP, I can't read documentation. the query has to match this query

```
SELECT 
    form_number, 
    code_b, 
    local_governments.lga, 
    local_governments.code, 
    concat(local_governments.code,code_b)  
FROM 
    `applicants` 
        left join local_governments 
            on applicants.local_government_id=local_governments.id 
where 
    printed=0
```

Comment: Post your code if you want that someone help you

Comment: @Alessandro This is my code, I am currently using just a findall but i want to change it to that commented part.function download() { $this->set('applicants', $this->Applicant->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Applicant.printed'=>0)))‌​); //$this->Applicant->query("SELECT form_number, code_b, local_governments.lga, code, concat(code,code_b) FROM applicants left join local_governments on applicants.local_government_id=local_governments.id where printed=0;"); $this->layout = null; $this->autoLayout = false; Configure::write('debug', '0'); }

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you models are setup correctly and associated correctly as well.

```
$applicants = $this->Applicant->find('all', 
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Applicant.printed' =>  0,
        ),
        'contain' => array('LocalGovernment'),
        'fields' => array(
            'Applicant.form_number', 
            'Applicant.code_b', 
            'LocalGovernment.lga', 
            'LocalGovernment.code', 
        )
    )
);
```

As for your concat... just do that when displaying the value in the view.

I hope this helps... let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but its only fetching rows from the Applicants table. I added public $actsAs = array('Containable'); to the applicant.php model but its still not fetching rows from local_governments table. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your models both Applicant and LocalGoverment

Comment: for Applicant.php `public $belongsTo = array(
   'LocalGovernment' => array(
    'className' => 'LocalGovernment',
    'foreignKey' => 'local_government_id',
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
   ),` and for LocalGovernment.php 
 `public $hasMany = array(
  'Applicant' => array(
   'className' => 'Applicant',
   'foreignKey' => 'local_government_id',
   'dependent' => false,
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => '',
   'limit' => '',
   'offset' => '',
   'exclusive' => '',
   'finderQuery' => '',
   'counterQuery' => ''
  )`

Comment: if you remove the conditions option... do you get back results with the associated LocalGovernemt?

Comment: Which of the condition options should i remove? I removed from the applicants controller and from both the applicant and localgovernment model. but it still does not work. Thank you for your help.